# Query to URL conversion

Tags: c#, android, sql, odata, odata4j

I have a query like this

```
select * from xxx where dates between '2012-10-26' and '2012-10-27'.
```

and did as URL like

```
url/?$filter=dates gt datetime'2012-10-26' and dates lt datetime'2012-10-27'
```

and I am getting response by using this one.

Now, I need to **get by time**, so I changed the URL to

```
&$filter=LastModifiedDate+ge+datetime'2012-09-25 23:59:59'
```

But I am getting an error:

> {"odata.error":{"code":"","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Unrecognized 'Edm.DateTime' literal 'datetime'2012-09-25 12:00:00'' at '20' in 'LastModifiedDate ge datetime'2012-09-25 12:00:00''."}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

```
dateTimeOffsetValue = year "-" month "-" day "T" hour ":" minute [ ":" second [ "." fractionalSeconds ] ] ( "Z" / sign hour ":" minute )
```

Example: 2000-01-01T16:00:00.000Z

---

> The edm:Date expression evaluates to a primitive date value. A date
>   expression MUST be assigned a value of type xs:date, see
>   [XML-Schema-2], section 3.3.9. The value MUST also conform to rule
>   dateValue in [OData-ABNF], i.e. it MUST NOT contain a time-zone
>   offset.

- http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-os-part3-csdl.html#_Toc372794020

> date represents top-open intervals of exactly one day in length on the
>   timelines of dateTime, beginning on the beginning moment of each day,
>   up to but not including the beginning moment of the next day).  For
>   non-timezoned values, the top-open intervals disjointly cover the
>   non-timezoned timeline, one per day.  For timezoned values, the
>   intervals begin at every minute and therefore overlap.

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime

Hence, what you want here is a `DateTimeOffset`:

> The edm:DateTimeOffset expression evaluates to a primitive date/time
>   value with a time-zone offset. A date/time expression MUST be assigned
>   a value of type xs:dateTimeStamp, see [XML-Schema-2], section 3.4.28.
>   The value MUST also conform to rule dateTimeOffsetValue in
>   [OData-ABNF], i.e. it MUST NOT contain an end-of-day fragment
>   (24:00:00).

- http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-os-part3-csdl.html#_Toc372794021
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTimeStamp
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime